# C++ remainder returns 7 at higher numbers

Tags: c++

So I am still pretty new to programming and trying to learn C++ so slowly figuring it out.

Right now I am trying to attempt the credit card number problem and trying to isolate each digit in the number so like.

```
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int creditcardnumber;
    cout << "Enter a 16-digit credit card number: "; // asks for credit       card number
    cin >> creditcardnumber;
    cin.ignore();
    int d16 = creditcardnumber % 10;

    cout << d16;

}
```

at lower numbers like : 123456
it returns 6 which is what I want
but at a higher number like : 12387128374
it returns 7 
I started noticing that it keeps returning 7 every time at higher numbers can anyone explain this and how to resolve it?

Comment: 12387128374  will overflow an int

Comment: Use a type that's at least 64 bits wide, like `int64_t` from the `cstdint` header.

Comment: Use `unsigned long long` instead of `int`.

Comment: Won't this be easier if you used a `std::string` for the credit card number instead of an int?

Comment: Realistically, you should use a string, rather than a numeric type.  As a rule of thumb: if you aren't doing math on it, it's not a number.

Answer (score 5):

that's because the biggest value of int (assuming an int size is 4 bytes) is 2147483647. your test exceeds it by far.
try to use bigger type, like long.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simple test program to illustrate your problem:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
  int x;
  std::cin >> x;
  std::cout << x << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

If the input stream is

```
123456789123
```

(for example), the output is

```
2147483647
```

What this shows is that if you try to enter a number that is larger than
the largest possible value of an `int`, you will end up with just
the largest `int` instead, which is 2147483647.
And every larger number likewise will give the same result.

And of course `2147483647%10` evaluates to 7.

But in the end, I think the most relevant point was already made in
a comment: there is almost surely no good reason for you to store 
the credit card "number" in a numeric C++ type; 
`std::string` would be more appropriate.

Comment: @MooingDuck I did mention a workaround: use a non-numeric type. I suppose it would have been clearer if I had suggested a _particular_ non-numeric type, so I've updated the answer to do so.

Answer (score 3):

A 16-digit number requires about 54 bits to represent. `int` very probably isn't big enough. `long` may or may not be, depending on your implementation.

If you have a sufficiently modern C++ implementation, `long long` is guaranteed to be at least 64 bits wide, so you can probably use that.

As for why you're always getting 7, apparently an overflow in

```
cin >> creditcardnumber;
```

causes the maximum representable `int` value to be stored in `creditcardnumber`. On a typical modern system with 32-bit `int`, that value is 2<sup>31</sup>-1, or `2147483647`. (On a system with 16-bit `int`, it happens that the maximum value is `32767`, and you'd also get `7` as the last digit on overflow.)

<strike>I'm not sure what the C++ standard says about the behavior of `cin >> n` on overflow.</strike> On overflow, `cin >> n`, where `n` is some type of integer, is defined to set `n` to the minimum or maximum value of its type. It also sets `failbit`, so you can detect the error. Reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt

Note that even if you use `long long`, which can hold a 16-digit decimal number, you can still get an overflow if the user enters an invalid number that exceeds 2<sup>63</sup>-1. (If that behaves the same way, the last digit also happens to be `7`; there seems to be some interesting mathematics at work here, but it's not relevant to your problem.)

Comment: `(2^n-1)%10` is a repeating pattern of 4 digits: 1, 3, 7, 5.  Since n=64 and n=32 are different by an exact multiple of four, they modulo to the same value.  (Same with 16bit, 12bit, 8bit, and 4bit)

Answer (score 0):

You experience integer overflow. You can check if input succeeded this way

```
if ( cin >> creditcardnumber) {
        // do your things
} else {
        cout << "Please enter a valid integer" << endl;
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore( numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
}
```